# Contenteditable on label tag does not work in firefox

Tags: firefox, label, contenteditable

Is there any way to make the text of a label editable in Firefox other than placing it in a span?

```
    <h1>Content Editable Test</h1>

    <p contenteditable="true">Can edit this</p>

    <p><label><span contenteditable="true">and this</span></label></p>

    <p><label contenteditable="true">but not this in Firefox</label></p>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but this is the only bug report that I've found https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853519

Comment: Also true in Safari. The span workaround is good for both browsers.